Http transport : Log buffering when offline
I have a nodeJS app running on a RPI with Winston as logger. It sends logs to a custom express api, using the built in http transport. However due to some instabilities on the internet connection on the RPI location, it seems that some logs are lost (typically if it tries to send a batch of log when the internet connection is down).
Is there a simple way /configuration to buffer the log until the connection is back ?

Do it on your own? Code a custom transport that does what you want. Seems like "developers" these days can only use modules and copy/paste code. what have you tried so far?

You’re right why does npm  even exist ? Lets just do everything from scratch every time.

If there is no ready to use package, its up to. Im sure you searched there and found nothing, thats you asked here.

Sounds crazy to me that a package like Winston does not handle this case. That’s why I asked, thinking I was missing something.
